# Two parallel tasks in VBA, Is it possible?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement, where I search an excel. Since I am looping through all the rows and columns ( many rows and columns), its taking time. I want to display a message box while the search operation is going on.

Is it possible to do in VBA?

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: What exactly do you want to display during search? Have you tried with userform?

Comment: Perhaps there is a quicker way to do it, like use Excel's native search capability

Answer (score 2):

`doevents` interrupts the current thread and allows the user environment to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

One of the eternal issues with VBA is its limitation of threads. VBA was conceived as a single-threaded model. Ever since, it remained so. Building a macro with multithread in native VBA is impossible.

Few workarounds are to build DLLs with COM interface and summon them in VBA or create worker scripts in VBS and use them from VBA.

This limitation of single thread widely annoys developers when it comes to display progress bar in excel. There is no API to communicate with the inbuilt progress bar of the Excel.
If you are looking to visually notify the user about some work that is under progress and they need to wait, all you are left with is either statusbar text or wait cursor. Another approach and bit intricate, because of their modal and non-modal styles, is to use UserForms. One more method, but very clumsy, unstable and non-native, is to use Internet Explorer object and update its HTML.

vba code :http://ashuvba.blogspot.in/2014/10/ajax-style-progress-display-in-vba.html

Answer (score 0):

VBA is single-threaded, so the boring answer is "nope, can't be done".

Also, displaying a messagebox would block your only thread, so using one should be out of the question.

You have several alternatives.

1. Report progress in the host application's status bar. This can make your long-running task run even longer though, because now on top of the actual work, you need to refresh a UI element - `DoEvents` can help a bit here.
2. Report progress in a custom userform. This can be tricky, because you probably don't want that form to actually *own* the code/logic that performs whatever it is that your long-running task does; you'll need to encapsulate that logic in a class/object, and let the form call into that object - the object exposes some `Public Event UpdateProgress`, and then the form needs to declare some `Private WithEvents myLogic As MyObject` to handle that event.
3. Wrap a .NET `BackgroundWorker` into a COM-visible library, and let .NET create the background thread for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I mimic progressbar when the code runs long:

- add separate hidden sheet like that:
  [image]

  (white background, range `B2:G2` merged and formatted as %, all other rows/columns hidden)
- apply conditional formatting to `B2`: Data bars - Lowest value: 0, Highest value 1, choose progressbar background color
- when the code starts running, unhide and activate it, on progress change `B2` value (0->0%, 1->100%), and call DoEvents to invalidate
- hide this sheet and activate the main sheet on completion